# How can i get an xpath or any other element for these drop downs, ? Select options or the (Sendkeys) works

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, elements

How can I get an XPath or any other element for these dropdowns? Now for the first drop down with the value= 'Adrian Clarke,' I was able to get the Xpath and run it successfully. For the second drop-down I got the Xpath but since its the same name name' Adrian Clarke' i believe its not a unique Xpath and therefore it fails. Select functionality nor sends keys work or CSS Selector works. Is there any way around for this?

[image]

Comment: Is it the correct screenshot? "Adrian Clarke" appears nowhere in it.

Comment: Have you tried the `ChroPath` extension? It is really handy when trying to find the locators of elements. Link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use something like this:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(yourXpath));

for(WebElement element : elements){
    //actions with elements you intend to perform
    // or use index for any specific element in list
}
```